# How to update the row indexes of a dynamic table when a row is deleted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm creating table rows dynamically by clicking in Add button. I want to add serial numbers to the rows created which works fine. But when row is deleted I want the existing row numbers to get updated which is not 
working.

Please ignore the undefined in the Name column.. That's some minor issue and not of concern.. Jquery solutions also fine.

Below is the code..

```js
function addRow() {
  var myName = document.getElementById("name");
  var table = document.getElementById("myTableData");
  var rowCount = table.rows.length;
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
  row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = '<input type="button" value = "Delete" onClick="Javacsript:deleteRow(this)">';
  row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = name.value;
  row.insertCell(2).innerHTML = row.rowIndex;
}

function deleteRow(obj) {
  var index = obj.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
  var table = document.getElementById("myTableData");
  table.deleteRow(index);
}

function addTable() {
  var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("myDynamicTable");
  var table = document.createElement('TABLE');
  table.border = '1';
  var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
  table.appendChild(tableBody);
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('TR');
    tableBody.appendChild(tr);
    for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
      var td = document.createElement('TD');
      td.width = '75';
      td.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Cell " + i + "," + j));
      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
  }
  myTableDiv.appendChild(table);
}

function load() {
  console.log("Page load finished");
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>HTML dynamic table using JavaScript</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="load()">
  <div id="myform"> <b>Simple form with name and age ...</b> 
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Name:</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" id="name">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="button" id="add" value="Add" onclick="Javascript:addRow()">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="mydata"> <b>Current data in the system ...</b> 
    <table id="myTableData" border="1" cellpadding="2">
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><b>Name</b>
        </td>
        <td><b>Sr no</b>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>&nbsp;
    <br/>
  </div>
  <div id="myDynamicTable"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm sorry I'm a newbie in javascript and so couldn't understand the other solutions much    :(  It'll be greatly helpful if someone can modify this code

Comment: That is not how SO works. If you could write the above code, you should be able to modify it. If you did NOT write the above code and do not know how to modify it, it is more an elance question which is off topic here. Anyway I will take a look

Comment: Here is a working version. Please note I added a class to the cell with the serial number and removed the body onload! I use window.onload instead
https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/y1rqdzcw/ - I also fixed your name issue

Comment: Thank you so much sir.. Your renumber function 
made me understand. I couldn't follow the i+1 logic earlier.. You made it simple to understand..